# Python AttributeError with initialised class variable

Tags: python, blockchain, attributeerror

I've recently been building a blockchain in Python. In my `Block` class, I initialise a `nonce` variable, which is then used later on in the class. However, when I try to use the variable elsewhere in the class, I get `AttributeError: 'Block' object has no attribute 'nonce'`. Here is my code:

```
from hashlib import sha256


class Block():
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.timestamp = str(time.time())
        self.data = data
        self.previousHash = '0'*64
        self.hash = self.calculateHash()
        self.nonce = 0

        self.dict = {
            "Previous hash": self.previousHash,
            "Hash": self.hash,
            "Timestamp": self.timestamp,
            "Data": self.data
        }

    def mineBlock(self, difficulty):
        while self.hash[:difficulty] != '0'*difficulty:
            self.nonce += 1
            self.calculateHash()

        print('Block mined: ' + self.hash)

    def calculateHash(self):
        hashingText = f'{self.timestamp}{self.data}{self.previousHash}{self.nonce}'.encode(
            'utf-8')

        return sha256(hashingText).hexdigest()
```

Here is the last part of the error, in case it helps:

```
File "/Users/[MYNAME]/Developer/DigiGov/src/BlockClass.py", line 28, in calculateHash
    hashingText = f'{self.timestamp}{self.data}{self.previousHash}{self.nonce}'.encode(
AttributeError: 'Block' object has no attribute 'nonce'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `__init__` method you do

```
        self.hash = self.calculateHash()
```

before you do:

```
        self.nonce = 0
```

`calculateHash()` depends on `nonce`, but it hasn't been set yet. Switch the order of those statements.

Comment: Yep, this works perfectly and fixes my issue. Thank you!